# Performance issue with C# threading task and multiple web page downloads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm running code to download a large number of documents from county websites, usually tax statements. The code I'm running seems fast and efficient in the beginning, and works great until the file count reaches about 200. This is when performance begins to plummet.  If I let it keep running, it still works, but gets to a point where it's painfully slow. I usually have to stop it, figure out which files haven't been downloaded, and start it over.

Any help on making this faster, more efficient, and smooth (regardless of file count) would be greatly appreciated.

I've been convinced the performance issue has to do with immediately writing the results to an html file.. I've tried storing the results in StringBuilder until the downloads finish, but of course I run out of memory.

I've also tried adjusting the MaxDegreeOfParallelism, which seemed to make a small impact by lowering it to 5, but the performance problem related to file count still exists.

```
    private void Run_Mass_TaxBillDownload()
    {
        string strTag = null;
        string county = countyName.SelectedItem.ToString() + "-";

        //Converting urlList to uriList...
        List<Uri> uriList = new List<Uri>();
        foreach (string url in TextViewer.Lines)//"TextViewer is a textbox where urls to be downloaded are stored...
        {
            if (url.Length > 5){Uri myUri = new Uri(url.Trim(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);uriList.Add(myUri);}
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(uriList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, str =>
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                //Extracting taxbill numbers from the url to use as file names in the saved file...
                string FirstString = null;
                string LastString = null;
                if (str.ToString().ToLower().Contains("&tptick")) { FirstString = "&TPTICK="; LastString = "&TPSX="; }
                if (str.ToString().ToLower().Contains("&ticket=")) { FirstString = "&ticket="; LastString = "&ticketsuff="; }
                if (str.ToString().ToLower().Contains("demandbilling")) { FirstString = "&ticketNumber="; LastString = "&ticketSuffix="; }

                //Start downloading...
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(clientTaxBill_DownloadStringCompleted);
                client.DownloadStringAsync(str, county + (Between(str.ToString(), FirstString, LastString)));
            }
        });
    }
    private static void clientTaxBill_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating Output file....
        string deskTopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string outputPath = deskTopPath + "\\Downloaded Tax Bills";
        string errOutputFile = outputPath + "\\errorReport.txt";
        string results = null;
        string taxBillNum = e.UserState as string;

        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(outputPath + "\\" + taxBillNum + ".html", e.Result.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            results = Environment.NewLine + "<<{ERROR}>> NOTHING FOUND FOR" + taxBillNum;
            File.AppendAllText(errOutputFile, results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, one simple optimization would be to find out which files already exist, and not download them again.

Comment: I have never tried this before, but couldn't you write the file asynchronously?  That would allow it to be a non-blocking call, not run into out of memory issues, and not have to wait for the file write to continue.  Just a thought...not fully fleshed out.

Comment: Thanks grooveplex, but downloading the same file twice is not a problem here..

Comment: `client.DownloadStringAsync` does this not just carry on? not tested but if it does you will end up with more than 5 concurrent jobs

Comment: for this type of code, I would look at `ActionBlock` its a much better pattern.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in debugging or added logging to record start/end times of operations? Where is the slowdown? Are you sure it's the actual write and not retrieving the document from the server? Have you checked to make sure the target server is not throttling your download speed or adding latency to your requests because you're making too many requests in too short a period? This is not a terribly uncommon thing.

Answer (score 1):

If `DownloadStringAsync` just carries on, then it will run more than 5 downloads at once, `DownloadStringCompleted` will setup the call back then just continue and loop around again.

So, it will not be waiting for each one to complete.

`ActionBlock` is your friend as its just works better with `async` code and couple that with `httpClient` instead of `WebClient`

Try something  like this

```
public static async Task Downloader()
{
    var urls = new string[] { "https://www.google.co.uk/", "https://www.microsoft.com/" };

    var ab = new ActionBlock<string>(async (url)  => 
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var text = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // just write it to a file
        Console.WriteLine(text);

    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        await ab.SendAsync(url);
    }

    ab.Complete(); 
    await ab.Completion;
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5` that says, 5 threads, `wait ab.SendAsync(url);` is important as if you want to restrict the buffer size with `BoundedCapacity = n` this will wait until it has room whereas the `ab.Post()` method will not, it will just return `false` if it has no room

Comment: Drake, I cant even try your suggestion.. I've got a reference to System.Threading.Tasks, but ActionBlock is not recognized? Am I missing a specific DLL somewhere to use this?